# Android Studio 1.0.2 Missing Styles

Tags: android, android-studio, android-styles

I just started using Android Studio.  I created my first "HelloAndroid" project in it, and under layout, I opened activity_main.xml.  The view is not rendered well as expected.  It shows an error:  "Rendering Problems: Missing Styles.  Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?"[image]

I'm new to Android Studio, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.  When I was using Eclipse with the ADK plugin I didn't have to configure anything to render successfully.

Comment: xml? for `textViewStyle`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the appCompat dependency in your gradle build file.

Answer (score 0):

Click the green robot icon to choose lower android version then press refresh button.

Similar to this question too.

[activity_main.xml: Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130771996](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824136/activity-main-xml-failed-to-find-the-style-corresponding-to-the-id-2130771996)

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this myself and it turns out I did not have the lowest SDK installed for the minimum I had selected. Make sure when selecting your minimum SDK that you have it installed.