# Eclipse fails to load AppTheme for the XML layout after the new project is created,Displays failed to find style corresponding

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, android-layout, new-project

I face this problem whenever the new projects is created in Eclipse

```
Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130772021 
Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130771993     
java.lang.NullPointerException 
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log 
The following classes could not be instantiated:
 - android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log) 
See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the above problem by just changing the theme like you just need to change your theme to any of the themes other than default theme.

Answer (score 0):

Specify value of android version to lower values in graphical layout view

[activity_main.xml: Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130771996](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824136/activity-main-xml-failed-to-find-the-style-corresponding-to-the-id-2130771996)

Answer (score 0):

in "MainActivity", please use "AppCompatActivity" instead of "Activity" or "ActionBarActivity".

Comment: This is a theme related problem.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to restart eclipse and run it as administrator some times sdk is in c drive need to be loaded as administrator.