# Android API 22 loading error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, android-developer-api

I created an Android Project in Eclipse Luna targeting API 22 and the minimum sdk was set to API 8, when I tried to open the activity_main xml file, the rendering worked fine for all other versions(shown below in first screenshot) but 22(second screenshot)
[image: For API 21]
[image]

And the error logs are in the second screenshot. I am just trying out Android development and I am really confused. Does anyone know if this is a problem I caused or is it a bug? Thanks a bunch.

The error log:

Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130772026

Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130771996

java.lang.NullPointerException

Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log

The following classes could not be instantiated:

-android.support.v7.internal.app.WindowDecorActionBar (Open Class, Show Error Log)

See the Error Log (Window > Show View) for more details.

Comment: Better to Jump on `Android Studio`.

Comment: Why's that? I've seen a lot of people using Eclipse. And the tutorial I found was using Eclipse.

Comment: Sooner or later you will have to start using android studio since it is the official ide now. So if you are a beginner i advise you find some tutorials using android studio.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29824136/activity-main-xml-failed-to-find-the-style-corresponding-to-the-id-2130771996

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is there. Go to style.xml and write this item  in appcompat.light parent style.

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> 
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether required things are installed or not specially related to API level 22 using sdk manager and restart both sdk manager and IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Make your Activity extend Activity by importing android.app.Activity; It will solve the problem and remove appcompat7 reference from main_Activity